# Change image of a button whithout going into the server with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a button that has a image and uses a MVC Ajax Form(Not Jquery) but I want change the button image to a loading element via Jquery, how can I do this using a element img that is already loaded in the page (if load from server it lost the purpose of immediatly show a loading element).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a tiled button image and careful position, then changing the class will change the *apparent* image without loading anything new.

e.g. say your button image is 2*50px wide (ie 100px wide)

### CSS

```
button {
  background: url('path/button.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
}

button.pic{
  background: url('path/button.png') 50px 0 no-repeat;//offset the image to show 2nd half
}
```

There'a good article on the technique here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites2/

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery:

```
<img id="my_image" src="button_image.jpg"></img>

$("#my_image").attr("src","loading.jpg");
```

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) is used to set attribute of html element. In this case we change src property.